# How to get server name(example : tomcat, weblogic) in Datasource.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I am looking for server name in Datasource, depends on server name I need to write some logic, I know that can get server info from controller using below line of code

```
getServletContext().getServerInfo()
```

But I need the server name in Datasource.groovy

Comment: By server name do you mean the container that runs your application? Not the server hostname from user@host? 

However, it lookes like this class provides the servletContext http://docs.grails.org/3.3.0/api/grails/util/Holders.html should work in grails 2.x also